Microsoft Graph Explorer sample Go code return undefined - undeclared imported name
In Graph Explorer using user mailbox query to generate sample Go code with the following query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/mailFolders('inbox')/messages/delta?$skiptoken={system generated token}
The code produced is:
// Code snippets are only available for the latest major version. Current major version is $v1.*

// Dependencies
import (
    "context"
    msgraphsdk "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go"
    graphusers "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/users"
    //other-imports)

requestSkiptoken := "token"

requestParameters := &graphusers.UserItemMailFolderItemMessagesDeltaWithRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters{Skiptoken: &requestSkiptoken,}

configuration := &graphusers.UserItemMailFolderItemMessagesDeltaWithRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration{QueryParameters: requestParameters,}

// To initialize your graphClient, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?from=snippets&tabs=go
delta, err := graphClient.Users().ByUserId("user-id").MailFolders().ByMailFolderId("mailFolder-id").Messages().Delta().GetAsDeltaGetResponse(context.Background(), configuration)

However, both UserItemMailFolderItemMessagesDeltaWithRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters and UserItemMailFolderItemMessagesDeltaWithRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration are tagged as undefined in vscode.
I can even build the same query and configuration parameters using the code guide in vscode, but the results are the same.
This is not true for any of the other parameters I have tried including other Delta use cases like: ItemMailFoldersItemMessagesDeltaRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters.
Any insight would be appreciated.
